# ¿Cómo rellenar celdas de una columna en un DataFrame con el promedio de los valores agrupados?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

Tengo un archivo de datos separados por comas (csv), el cual tiene 4 columnas (`index`, `planta`, `producto`, `velocidad de producción`), tal como se muestra:

> index,planta,producto,velocidad de producción
>   0,Planta 1,producto 1,40
>   1,Planta 3,producto 2,20
>   2,Planta 1,producto 1,NaN
>   3,Planta 1,producto 1,50
>   4,Planta 3,producto 2,25

En los datos del ejemplo en el renglón con índice 2 no hay dato en la velocidad de producción, por lo que quiero reemplazar el valor NaN por el promedio de los renglones con índice 0 y 3 ya que al agruparlos por `planta` y `producto` son los que corresponden a ese grupo.

Mi código hasta el momento es:

```
import sys
import pandas as pd

prod = pd.read_csv('datos_produccion.csv', index_col = 0, encoding = 'utf-8')
prod.apply(lambda x: pd.lib.infer_dtype(x.values))

lista_productos= prod[['planta', 'producto', 'velocidad de producción']]

#antes de generar un nuevo archivo deseo agrupar los datos y rellenar los faltantes
prod.to_csv('listra_produccion.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente calcula la media de cada grupo y luego asignala a los valores nulos. Para calcular la media puedes usar [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) y luego aplicar [`pandas.DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) sobre la columna `velocidad de producción` de cada grupo. Con ello obtendría algo así:

```
>>> groups_means

index
0    45.0
1    22.5
2    45.0
3    45.0
4    22.5
Name: velocidad de producción, dtype: float64
```

Hecho esto simplemente tienes que filtrar los valores nulos de la columna con `loc` y asignarles el valor medio que les pertenece según su grupo usando:

```
import pandas as pd

prod = pd.read_csv('datos.csv', index_col=0, encoding='utf-8')
groups_means = prod.groupby(["planta", "producto"])['velocidad de producción'].transform('mean')
prod.loc[prod['velocidad de producción'].isnull(), 'velocidad de producción'] = groups_means
```

**Salida:**

```
>>> prod

         planta    producto  velocidad de producción
index                                               
0      Planta 1  producto 1                     40.0
1      Planta 3  producto 2                     20.0
2      Planta 1  producto 1                     45.0
3      Planta 1  producto 1                     50.0
4      Planta 3  producto 2                     25.0
```

> **Nota:**
>
> `pd.lib.infer_dtype` está actualmente marcado como "Deprecated" y dejará de estar disponible en futuras versiones de Pandas. En su lugar usa `prod.apply(lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x.values))`.

Comment: Cuando reemplazo la linea de código pd.lib.infer_dtype por prod.apply(lambda x: pd.api.types.infer_dtype(x.values)) me aparece el siguiente error AttributeError: ("'module' object has no attribute 'infer_dtype'", 'occurred at index indice'). ¿A que se debe?